# Creating a dummy varuable based on a criteria in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe like this:

```
date           sales      company    country 
16/03/2012     3000       H&M        US
13/04/2012     2300       H&M        US
26/03/2012     1230       H&M        FR
13/04/2012     1300       H&M        FR
23/03/2012     2230       H&M        IT
19/04/2012     1100       H&M        IT
16/03/2012     3000       ABC        US
13/04/2012     2300       ABC        US
26/03/2012     100        ABC        FR
13/04/2012     60         ABC        FR
23/03/2012     435        ABC        IT
19/04/2012     300        ABC        IT
```

I want to define a criteria: A company is considered to be an internatinal if less than 50% of its (avarage)sales coming from the single country. I want to create a new column that takes the value of 1 if it is international and 0 otherwise. Final output should look something like this:

```
 date           sales      company    country   international
    16/03/2012     3000       H&M        US         1
    13/04/2012     2300       H&M        US         1
    26/03/2012     1230       H&M        FR         1
    13/04/2012     1300       H&M        FR         1
    23/03/2012     2230       H&M        IT         1
    19/04/2012     1100       H&M        IT         1
    16/03/2012     3000       ABC        US         0
    13/04/2012     2300       ABC        US         0
    26/03/2012     100        ABC        FR         0
    13/04/2012     60         ABC        FR         0
    23/03/2012     435        ABC        IT         0
    19/04/2012     300        ABC        IT         0
```

How I could do that ?
P.S: There might be missing sales values in the dataset, how could I say ignore those values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) for means, comapre them and groupby with aggregate `all` for check if all values return `True`s:

```
s2 = df.groupby('company')['sales'].transform('mean') / 2
print (s2)
0     930.00
1     930.00
2     930.00
3     930.00
4     930.00
5     930.00
6     516.25
7     516.25
8     516.25
9     516.25
10    516.25
11    516.25
Name: sales, dtype: float64

s1 = df.groupby(['company', 'country'])['sales'].transform('mean')
print (s1)
0     2650.0
1     2650.0
2     1265.0
3     1265.0
4     1665.0
5     1665.0
6     2650.0
7     2650.0
8       80.0
9       80.0
10     367.5
11     367.5
Name: sales, dtype: float64
```

---

```
df['international'] = (s1 > s2).groupby(df['company']).transform('all').astype(int)
print (df)
          date  sales company country  international
0   16/03/2012   3000     H&M      US              1
1   13/04/2012   2300     H&M      US              1
2   26/03/2012   1230     H&M      FR              1
3   13/04/2012   1300     H&M      FR              1
4   23/03/2012   2230     H&M      IT              1
5   19/04/2012   1100     H&M      IT              1
6   16/03/2012   3000     ABC      US              0
7   13/04/2012   2300     ABC      US              0
8   26/03/2012    100     ABC      FR              0
9   13/04/2012     60     ABC      FR              0
10  23/03/2012    435     ABC      IT              0
11  19/04/2012    300     ABC      IT              0
```

Comment: I had something similar but no chance of doing this before you guys get a response. However I'd change df2 and df1 to s1 and s2 as they are series and not dataframes +1

Comment: vaaw great answer :)